# Trigger a JavaScript action when shift-double clicking

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am moving from Safari to Chrome and desperately miss the Safari zoom behavior.  There's an extension [dblclickzoomin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dblclickzoomin/flcpghpdcjpneanjmojaimmmghnoondg) that makes things zoom like safari whenever you doubleclick.  However, this is supremely annoying!  I double click to select full words of text, etc.!

Can I modify the code to make it work when I hold shift and double click?

The trigger bit of the code is:

```
init: function(){
      window.addEventListener("dblclick",Zoomer,false);
    },
```

Since shift-dblclick (or better, shift triple click) isn't a standard DOM trigger... does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `event.shiftKey` property to determine if the Shift key was depressed during double-click:

```
window.addEventListener("dblclick", function(e){
    if(e.shiftKey) {
        Zoomer.apply(this, arguments); // call Zoomer with same `this` and args
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: thanks so much for taking a look!  It actually seems super close to a solution, but it still doesn't seem to work... Maybe it's something about the arguments? I think zoomer is actually a variable.  Any ideas?  Here's the full code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/myp4xiijy47o1ha/zoom.js

Comment: @user2362191 Hmm, I'll look at it later; for now I can only suggest possibly trying `Zoomer.call(this, e)` (also, verify that the event is triggered at all).

Comment: Cheers!  I tried swapping out `Zoomer.apply(this, arguments);` for `Zoomer.call(this, e);` ... and no joy...

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to take a look?  Thanks ever so much! @apsillers